# How to init a source in <Image> via parameter

Tags: react-native, image

Created Icon.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const Icon = ({onPress, path, style, size = 32}) => {
    const image = (
    <Image 
        source= {require(path)} // <- Here's the error
        style= {[{width: size, height: size, resizeMode: 'cover'}, style]}
    />
    );

    if(onPress) {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            {image}
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }
    return image;
};

export default Icon;
```

And then i Wanted to put my image in TabNavigator:

```
        <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => {
                return (
//Related code ->   <Icon path={'C:/react/Demo/src/assets/icons/Home.png'} size={40}/>
                )
            }
        }} />
```

Then I'm getting error src\components\Icon.js: src\components\Icon.js:Invalid call at line 7: require(path)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using a relative path like ```../src/assets/icons/Home.png```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I cant put source in variable, because require accepts only string. Did this:

```
const Icon = ({ onPress, source, style, size = 32 }) => {
  const image = (
    <Image
      source= {source}
      style= {[{ width: size, height: size, resizeMode: 'cover' }, style]}
    />
  );
}
```

And then:

```
<Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{
  tabBarIcon: () => {
    return (
      <Icon source={require('C:/react/Demo/src/assets/icons/User.png')} size={40}/>
    )
  }
}}>
```